# .htaccess take .php off, leading to wrong directory

Tags: .htaccess

So, I'm trying to take .php from my URLs and make it so its page and not page.php however I'm having problems because as soon as you go to a directory and a page it puts you to the main directory... So example if its /example/page.php it will take you to /page and not /example/page

This is the .htaccess I've tried.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all of your rules with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: No still having the same issue. Just making sure its saved and updated.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed this now, however all my urls are going to /pageName/css and stuff and not just /css

Comment: That is due to your use of relative paths in HTML. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Did that help solving the problem?